# Keras - Loss and Metric calculated differently?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, loss, metric

I have a model in Keras which I'm optimizing the mean squared error. However, if I use the same code as in `losses.py` from Keras in the metric, I get a different result. Why is this?

As a metric:

```
def MSE_metric(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.square(y_pred, y_true))
```

For the model:

```
model.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=0.01, momntum=0.9), loss='MSE', metrics=[MSE_metric])
```

This results in a loss of 6.07 but an MSE_metric of 0.47

Comment: We can't guess what your code looks like. :-)

Comment: It's kind of a general question, independent of the model. However, I'll post some code. If that's not enough, please ask for more! Thanks :)

Comment: Updated, with code.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Remember - that if you use any kind of regularization - it affects your `loss`. Your actual loss is equal to:

```
loss = mse + regularization
```

and this is where your discrepancy comes from.

Answer (score 1):

Marcin is right. [Here](https://github.com/sparklingdew/keras_loss_discrepancy) I've explored the effect of regularization and division into batches. Both affect the training loss recorded in logs, but regularization has the largest effect. It is always advisable to compute metrics using model.evaluate after fitting the model.
If wanting to see the 'actual' loss during training, one trick is to set the validation set identical to the training set (or a subset of the training set, if there is too much data). Validation metrics are simply evaluated on the fitted model, unlike training loss.